# How to use the rotation properties of the group to rotate the group ,and reposition it exactly in Konva.js with react

Tags: konvajs

First of all, Thank you for taking the time to answer my questions.

I am working for an small Image Editor project, Basing on konva.js with react.But I've run into some problems，that have bothered me for few days.
I want to use the rotation properties of the group to rotate the group, and all shapes in it, it works exactly, when clicking the rotate Button, but when I click the text Button, and want to draw it on the Image, and reposition exactly, the pic1 is my expected result, but actually, I got the unexpected result show as pic2, how can i do to rotate the group and all shapes in it exactly.

[image: pic]

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

My simple example show as following:

```js
class Test extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            historyArray: [],
            isTexting: true,
            image: new window.Image(),
            layerPos:{
                x: 300,
                y: 100,
            },
            imageWidth: 0,
            imageHeight: 0,
            rotateDegrees: 0,
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {

        const {historyArray} = this.state;
        this.state.image.setAttribute("crossOrigin", "anonymous");
        this.state.image.src = "https://vd.youniwote.com/homework/44evmey2cbd/submit/44evmey2cbe.jpg";
        this.state.image.onload = () => {
            let imageWidth = this.state.image.width > 620 ? 620 / (parseFloat(this.state.image.height) / parseFloat(this.state.image.width)) : this.state.image.width;
            let imageHeight = this.state.image.height > 620 ? 620 : this.state.image.height;
            let imageObj = {
                mode: 'image',
                image: this.state.image,
                width: imageWidth,
                height: imageHeight,
            }
            historyArray.push(imageObj);
            this.setState({
                historyArray,
                imageWidth,
                imageHeight,
            })
        }
    }
    clickStage = (event) => {
        const {mode, isTexting, historyArray} = this.state;
        if (mode == 'text') {
            if (isTexting) {
                let textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
                document.body.appendChild(textarea);
                textarea.style.position = 'absolute';
                textarea.style.top = event.evt.pageY + 'px';
                textarea.style.left = event.evt.pageX + 'px';
                textarea.style.width = 100;
                textarea.focus();

                this.setState({
                    isTexting: false,
                })

                textarea.addEventListener('keydown',  (e) => {
                    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                        historyArray.push({
                            mode: "text",
                            x:this.getActualPosInStage(event).x,
                            y: this.getActualPosInStage(event).y,
                            text: textarea.value,
                        })

                        document.body.removeChild(textarea);
                        this.setState({
                            isTexting: true,
                            historyArray
                        })
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    getActualPosInStage = (e) => {
        const {layerPos} = this.state;
        let stageBox = this.stage.getStage().getContainer().getBoundingClientRect();
        let mousePos = {
            x: e.evt.clientX,
            y: e.evt.clientY,
        }
        let x = Math.abs(mousePos.x - stageBox.left - layerPos.x);
        let y = Math.abs(mousePos.y - stageBox.top - layerPos.y);
        return {x,y}
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div style={{top: 0, left: 0}}>
                    <Button onClick={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            mode: 'text',
                            groupDraggable: false,
                        })
                    }}>Text</Button>

                    <Button style={{marginLeft: 20}} onClick={() => {
                        const {rotateDegrees} = this.state;
                        this.setState({
                            rotateDegrees: rotateDegrees + 90,
                            groupDraggable: false,
                            mode: 'rotate',
                        })

                        this.group.offsetX(this.group.width() / 2);
                        this.group.offsetY(this.group.height() / 2);

                        this.group.x(this.group.width() / 2);
                        this.group.y(this.group.height() / 2);

                    }}>Rotate</Button>
                </div>
                <Stage
                    onClick={(e) => {this.clickStage(e)}}
                    width={1000}
                    height={1000}
                    ref={node => {
                        this.stage = node;
                    }}
                >
                    <Layer
                        x={this.state.layerPos.x}
                        y={this.state.layerPos.y}
                        ref={node => {
                            this.layer = node;
                        }}
                    >
                        <Group
                            rotation={this.state.rotateDegrees}
                            width={this.state.imageWidth}
                            height={this.state.imageHeight}
                            ref={node => {
                                this.group = node;
                            }}
                        >
                            {
                                this.state.historyArray.map((item, index) => {
                                    if (item.mode == 'image') {
                                        return (
                                            <Image
                                                key={index}
                                                width={item.width}
                                                height={item.height}
                                                image={this.state.image}
                                                ref={node => {
                                                    this.imageNode = node;
                                                }}
                                            />
                                        )
                                    } else if (item.mode == 'text') {
                                        return(
                                            <Text
                                                key={index}
                                                x={item.x}
                                                y={item.y}
                                                text={item.text}
                                                fontSize={24}
                                                fill='red'
                                            />
                                        )
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        </Group>
                    </Layer>
                </Stage>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

These questions had bothered me few days, I would appriciate it , if anyone could answer my question

Comment: Some info about transformation sharing here : https://longviewcoder.com/2021/01/12/konva-shape-transform-sharing-is-simple/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a position of a text, you need to use position relative to the group. In your code, you are using position relative to top-left point of the stage. It gives you not correct result, because your group is moved and rotated.

So you need to calculate the position relative to the group. The simple way is to INVERT the absolute transform matrix of the group and apply to the mouse point:

```
const stage = e.target.getStage();
const pos = stage.getPointerPosition();

const absTransform = this.group.getAbsoluteTransform();

const invertedTransform = new Konva.Transform(
  absTransform.getMatrix()
).invert();

const shapePos = invertedTransform.point(pos);
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/l2k4k3y7n9

Comment: It works, Thank you very much for your help. You saved me a lot of time.